# .How to subtract a percentage from a csv file and then output it into another file? I'd preferably like a formula like x*.10=y

Tags: python, python-3.7

Sorry if I haven't explained things very well. I'm a complete novice please feel free to critic

I've searched every where but I havent found anything close to subtracting a percent. when its done on its own(x-.10=y) it works wonderfully. the only problem is Im trying to make 'x' stand for sample_.csv[0] or the numerical value from first column from my understanding.

```
import csv
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

readdata = csv.reader(open("sample_.csv"))
x = input(sample_.csv[0])

y = input(x * .10)

print(x + y)
```

the column looks something like this
    "20,a,"
    "25,b,"
    "35,c,"
    "45,d,"

Comment: no, you'd have to do it in steps. What have you tried so far?

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: my biggest problem is turning (x) into representative of the list

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only need pandas for this task. I'm guessing you want to apply this operation on one column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample_.csv') # assuming columns within csv header.
df['new_col'] = df['20,a'] * 1.1 # Faster than adding to a percentage x + 0.1x = 1.1*x
df.to_csv('new_sample.csv', index=False) # Default behavior is to write index, which I personally don't like.
```

BTW: input is a reserved command in python and asks for input from the user. I'm guessing you don't want this behavior but I could be wrong.

Comment: your assumption is correct I dont want input from user. the only problem with your response is it adds on 10% instead of removing it. what i want is 90% to be the answer let me see if it works works thanks. Just curious why do think I would need only pandas, were you disregarding "import csv" ?

Comment: Oh okay! Then sure you can just replace the "1.1" line with:
```df['new_col'] = df['20,a'] * 0.9```

The csv library is great, but it is usually too low level for most tabular tasks. You are going to get a lot of millage out of pandas because it speeds up applied operations on columns and has a lot of useful functions which exist more on the "data" level as opposed to the "file-io" level. I would highly recommend exploring the docs.

Comment: I'm only using one column why df [ ' 20,a ' ]  instead of just df [ ' 20 ' ]

Comment: Oh I thought that was the name of one column based on your quotes around column names in the first part. Yeah, just change it to '20'.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample_.csv")
df['newcolumn'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : x * .10)
```

Please try this.

Comment: I got quite a big error, any chance you could explain your code so that I may understand why it doesn't work on my end?

Comment: I ended up using a different csv file it ended up working thanks!

Comment: 'df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))  df['newcolumn'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x : x * .10) '